# Java collectingAndThen R is not convertible to Set<Post>

Tags: java-8, java-stream

There are a few similar questions here on the site but they used map which would have altered the type. I can't quite see what I'm doing wrong in this code I'm hoping someone can set me straight.

The code is taken from a JPARepository hence the findAll() but that can be ignored

Edit - returning the forEach is not going to work but I'm just concerned with the error about R not convertible. Added the signature for setPosts

```
boolean canViewHidden = hasAuthority(Permissions.Post.VIEWHIDDEN);
        //findAll should return List<Category>
        return categoryRepository.findAll().forEach(
                //each category has a Set<Post> accessible by getPosts
                category -> category.getPosts().stream()
                    //filtering out the posts that we can't view
                    .filter(post -> canViewHidden || !post.isHidden())

                     //my understanding is filter results in a Stream of Post
                     //however category::setPosts here gives the R is not convertible to Set<Post>                      
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), category::setPosts))
        );
```

setPosts method from Post.java

```
public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

//spring annotation can be ignored
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
private Set<Post> posts;
```

Comment: Doesn't `forEach` return void? I would be surprised if it works.

Comment: Anyway, could you post the signature of `setPosts`?

Comment: Edited thanks, you're right returning the foreach wouldn't work I originally was using Stream.of()... I'm really just concerned with the not convertible reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collectingAndThen` expects the second argument to be a `Function`, to allow the user to apply a last transformation to the collected `Collection`. However, `category::setPosts` is not transforming a collection, but it simply accepts one but returns `void`. That wouldn't work.

If you just want, for each category, to replace the posts list with a subset described by your stream operation, you can just do the following:

```
categoryRepository.findAll().forEach(category -> {
    Set<Post> posts = category.getPosts().stream()
        .filter(post -> canViewHidden || !post.isHidden())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    category.setPosts(posts);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't certain what Post was so I used String instead and filtered on String lengths of 2.  You should be able to adapt it to use any Class with the appropriate filter.

Here is what I came up with.  You said you wanted to return a list so I did that instead of set.  Note that you don't need to do a second transformation so `collectingAndThen` is not required.

```java
      List<Category> categoryRepository = new ArrayList<>();

      categoryRepository.add(
            new Category(Set.of("A", "B", "C", "DE", "FG", "ABC")));
      categoryRepository.add(new Category(
            Set.of("AAAA", "BBBB", "CC", "DDDE", "FFFG", "ABC", "12")));
      categoryRepository.add(
            new Category(Set.of("ARS", "AB", "CCC", "RE", "GG", "ABC")));

      List<String> list = categoryRepository.stream().flatMap(
            a -> a.getPosts().stream()).filter(a -> a.length() == 2).collect(
                  Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(list);
   }

}

class Category {
   private Set<String> posts;

   public Category(Set<String> posts) {
      this.posts = posts;
   }

   public Set<String> getPosts() {
      return posts;
   }
}
```

- The List is converted to a stream() of Category
- Then each Category retrieves the Set via getPosts() and is flatMapped to a common stream of Strings(these would be Posts for you).
- Then each String (Post) is filtered and placed in a List or Set of
  your chosing and returned.